# Scrolling EditText Content automatically in android

Tags: android

Is it possible to use horizontal scrolling on edittext view when the text inside the edittext is very large. And also can it automatically scroll to the left and show the hidden content when user enter the form

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/rlMP3SeekContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hint_deezer_search"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/eight_dp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/eight_dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
     android:textColorHint="sssssssssssosososskdddkdkdkdkdkddkowowowowwoeoekffkfkfkfkfkfkfkffkfkfkfkffkfkfkfkfoeeoeoeoeoeoeoeeoeoeoeoeoe"
        android:textSize="@dimen/fourteen_sp" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible with the following lines:

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

Then, the text you are entering will move left and will be in single Line.

Comment: will it scroll automatically ?

Comment: Yes. It will scroll automatically while typing. Edit your xml and check

Comment: How u want it to scroll?? Is it scrolling or not while you r typing?

Comment: What is the issue? Please let me know so that i can help u

Answer (score 1):

try adding

```
android:lines="1"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

like this

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/rlMP3SeekContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hint_deezer_search"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/eight_dp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/eight_dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
     android:textColorHint="sssssssssssosososskdddkdkdkdkdkddkowowowowwoeoekffkfkfkfkfkfkfkffkfkfkfkffkfkfkfkfoeeoeoeoeoeoeoeeoeoeoeoeoe"
        android:textSize="@dimen/fourteen_sp"
android:lines="1"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below to scrool down when you are writing

`android:isScrollContainer="true"`